# Adding a "SPAN" element to the React Code DOM causes a Java script error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a custom chrome extension, and in one website, there is a table that I want to add three to four columns to, however when I run my extension scripts, it gives me an error like this.
[error ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmf9s.png)

code::

```
        const containerSelector = '#root > div > main > div.custom-a3qv9n > div.ds-dex-table.ds-dex-table-new';
        const tableContainer = document.querySelector(containerSelector);
        const firstRow = tableContainer.querySelector('a.ds-dex-table-row.ds-dex-table-row-new');
        const newRow = firstRow.cloneNode(true); // Clone with content
        newRow.querySelectorAll('span.ds-table-data-cell').forEach(cell => {
          cell.textContent = "NB Value for this row"; // Replace with actual NB data
        });
        tableContainer.appendChild(newRow);
```

i tried to find issue with this and find out that when i append child it gives me error means whenever i updating DOM content it gives me error , i think my targeted website uses react

can i know what i am doing wrong ??

i ensured that my scripts is running after DOMcontentLoad

Comment: Please don't post image of the error.

Comment: @AizanSagheer is there any issue with that ? please give me reason as i am new to this platform

Comment: the error is raised in a minified code. Have you try run the script in an unminified application to get the true error ?

Comment: @jeremy-denis I need to run it in minified code because I am creating an extension for a website and I do not have an unminified application.