# Can we add span element by changing DOM in react website which updating every 2 seconds?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

I want to know if it is possible to add elements to a website that already has React built in and is updating often. When I tried to buil it, when the data updated and the element I had added has been removed , and I received an error in the console.

```
Uncaught Error: Minified React error #418 ;

Uncaught Error: Minified React error #422
```

so i gone through many solution but didnt work any so i want to know is it possible to add element in DOM which changes frequently

i tried with mutation observer in that i did like whenever mutation obeserver find changes in data it adding element again but didnt works !!!!!!!!!!!

for this one first time i can see the element added for just 2 seconds after it has removed when data is upaded

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
you can add element in the DOM but the best way to do this with React is to manage your DOM with state locale or state global or using context.

if the data is used for specified view/page it is good to use context.
The context will provide all of child components.

And every change of your data, there will re-render => it is time for you to manage the render, what you want to remove or to add in the DOM.

This is called conditional rendering.

May you need to learn more about Context, Hooks and [Custom Hooks](https://react.dev/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks)

Comment: indepth  problem :: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78178440/adding-a-span-element-to-the-react-code-dom-causes-a-java-script-error?noredirect=1#comment137827208_78178440]